# Searching text in pdf using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf, full-text-search

I am having a `big database` roughly it has 5 lakh (500K) entries now all those entries also have some document associated with them (i.e. every id has at least pdf file). Now I need a robust method to search for a particular `text` in those pdf files and if I find it, it should return the respective 'id'

kindly share some fast and optimized ways to `search text in a pdf using PHP`. Any idea will be appreciated.

note: Changing the pdf to text and then searching is not what I am looking for obviously, it will take a longer time.

> In one line I need the best way to search for text in pdf using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself wrote a website in ReactJS to search for info in PDF files (indexed books), which I indexed using Apache SOLR search engine.

What I did in React is, in essence:

```
queryValue = "(" + queryValueTerms.join(" OR ") + ")"

    let query = "http://localhost:8983/solr/richText/select?q="
    let queryElements = []

    
    if(searchValue){
      queryElements.push("text:" + queryValue)
    }

...

 fetch(query)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) =>{
        setSearchResults(prepareResults(result.response.docs, result.highlighting))
        setTotal(result.response.numFound)
        setHasContent(result.response.numFound > 0)
      })
```

Which results in a HTTP call:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/richText/select?q=text:(chocolate%20OR%20cake)
```

Since this is ReactJS and just parts of code, it is of little value to you in terms of PHP, but I just wanted to demonstrate what the approach was. I guess you'd be using Curl or whatever.

Indexing itself I did in a separate service, using SolrJ, i.e. I wrote a rather small Java program that utilizes SOLR's own SolrJ library to add PDF files to SOLR index.

If you opt for indexing using Java and SolrJ (was the easiest option for me, and I didn't do Java in years previously), here are some useful resources and examples, which I collected following extensive search for my own purposes:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/using-solrj.html#using-solrj

I basically copied what's here:
https://lucidworks.com/post/indexing-with-solrj/
and tweaked it for my needs.

Tip: Since I was very rusty with Java, instead of setting classpaths etc, quick solution for me was to just copy ALL libraries from SOLR's solrj folder, to my Java project. And possibly some other libraries. May be ugly, but did the job for me.

Comment: This is nice @Gishas but I am not using react.js. However I am planning to use ajax obviously for lower number of request hits, but can you please help me with a fast way to get text from pdf. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @rahul-kumar-jha Maybe "Elasticsearch" is what you need. It is based on Apache Lucene, like SOLR itself, but the word is that it is much easier, particularly for beginners, to set it up. I didn't work with it, but I did do some research. I like what Rick James wrote in his answer though. So, maybe there is no super-fast solution, but you may consider, if there is a possibility that you would need advanced search in some time, that you should consider spending several days to learn Elasticsearch basic options and implement it. It may be of great use in your project in future perhaps.

Comment: @ Gishas Ya sure definitely I will check out the elastic search, Thanks for the advice. Actually, I am working on a  larval ERP project and there I need to add this feature. However, I have made this earlier in my other projects as well but this time the challenge is the speed that's why I thought before I start making the algorithms, etc I should ask in the community if there is a better solution. And ya Rick James answer also referring to the same process. Well, let's see how to implement elastic search in Laravel.

Comment: @rahul-kumar-jha Yes, both SOLR and Elasticsearch seem to be blazing fast even with millions of documents. There is this brilliant research by Bill Karwin https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql which examines indexing speed, index size and reading speed of different search approaches (including SQL 'LIKE' operator). It is very concise, I recommend you give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-time task, there is probably no 'fast' solution.

If this is a recurring task,

1. Extract the text via some tool.  (Sorry, I don't know of a tool.)
2. Store that text in a database table.
3. Apply a `FULLTEXT` index to that table.

Now the searching will be fast.

Comment: The whitespace should be removed from a good PDF-to-text converter.  If you remove _all_ whitespace, then "words" are no longer distinguished, hence FULLTEXT is not useful (since it depends on "words").

Comment: Well, perhaps an "ngram" FULLTEXT might work.  (This, for example, is what is done with Chinese.)

Comment: Ya I also have decided to extract the text and then store it as json file also removing dump from it but I don't know what library or method is the fastest to get text from pdf

Comment: @RahulKumarJha - Is there any structure to the extracted text?  If not, simply use `MEDIUMTEXT`, not `JSON`.